# saveAstextFile is Spark on Windows

Tags: apache-spark

I know it's unusual configuration, but I I have Spark installed on Windows just for tests

I can easily use

```
val file_in = sc.textFile("UDP_file.txt")
```

on local filesystem. But when I try to use

```
names.saveAsTextFile("file:///file_out.txt")
```

I get an error:

```
14/08/21 13:06:12 ERROR FileOutputCommitter: Mkdirs failed to create file:/file_out.txt/_temporary/0
```

but actualy the path is created:

```
file_out.txt\_temporary\0\_temporary\attempt_201408211306_0000_m_000000_34
```

and with file `part-00000` insite the catalog.

Is it possible to `use saveAsTextFile` method on Spark installed on Windows?

Regards
Pawel

Comment: This is some kind of bug in spark. Even I am getting the same. For me the folder is getting created with nothing inside it... Anyways you had the question tagged wrongly. Instead of spark it should be tagged as apache spark

Answer (score 2):

> Instead of "file:///file_out.txt" try "file_out.txt".

It will create one folder (not file) "file_out.txt", so you can specify "file_out" also as the name.

Inside that folder you can see part-000* files.

Comment: The part-00000 file is empty.... How to I get Spark to create a real file? 
I am running Windows 7.

Comment: You can check number of partitions. Number of output files = Number of partitions in RDD.   (rdd.partitions.length )